# Технология получения ответа JSON посредством Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

С Ajax раньше не работал, возник вопрос с ним. Сайт подгружает страницы с использованием следующей jQuery конструкции:

> ```
> $.get('http://адрес', function(data) {
>   $("#page-content").html(data);
> });
> ```

Но мне нужно получить не только HTML запрошенной страницы, но и данные из PHP переменных, заголовок страницы из переменной, если быть точнее. Как это правильно реализовать? Я так понимаю, что нужно отправить Ajax запрос на PHP страницу (в моём случае), получить ответ в формате JSON и обработать его в JS. Можно простейший пример на jQuery?

И еще, возвращаемые JSON данные обязательно должны отобразиться в HTML? Просто все увиденные примеры выводят его так: `echo json_encode($json);`. Не хотелось бы засорять существующую страницу.

Comment: что то не понятно в чем вопрос? у вас в вопросе уже есть ответ

Comment: Таким образом подгружается вся страница, но не отдельные PHP переменные. Хочу пример реализации запроса переменных, чтобы работать с ними в JS.

Comment: Возвращайте данные с php через `echo json_encode($json);`, где `$json` это массив с html и с набором переменных: `$json = ['html => '', data => '']`, а обращаться будите так: `$("#page-content").html(data.html)` и к данным соответственно через точку

Comment: 1 вариант) сделайте отдельный файл, в котором в зависсимости от пришеджих параметров в запросе вы будите отдавать ответ `echo json_encode($json)` 2 вариант) Начните юзать фреймверк